# Cannot take view size using view tree observer

Tags: java, android

I am tying to get the width and height of a view in an adapter, while the view is not yet fully inflated, using a ViewTreeObserver, but I  always end up with zero values. The width and height are going to be used in a method that resizes a bitmap of an imageview in a listview in the adapter. Here is my code:

```html
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 newView = convertView;
 ViewHolder holder;

 if (null == convertView) {
  holder = new ViewHolder();
  newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selfie_list_view, null);
  holder.selfieView = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.selfie_bitmap);
  holder.selfieName = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.selfie_name);
  newView.setTag(holder);
  
 } else {
  holder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();
 }
 
 SelfieRecord curr = list.get(position);
 String selfieName = curr.getBitmapName();
 String selfiePath = curr.getBitmapPath();
 Bitmap selfie = setPic(newView, selfiePath);
 
 holder.selfieView.setImageBitmap(selfie);
 holder.selfieName.setText(selfieName);

 return newView;
}


private Bitmap setPic(final View view, String path) {
 
 ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
 if (vto.isAlive()) {
  vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    targetW = view.getWidth();
    targetH = view.getHeight();
    Log.i(TAG, "view_width = " + targetW + " view_height =" + targetH);   
    
   }
  });
 }
 
    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
  
 return bitmap;
}
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: `getMeasuredWidth()` instead 'getWidth()' ?

Comment: No, neither this is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it using an onPreDrawListener and putting the bitmap decoding and the imageview inside it. Here's the solution in case somebody needs it. Thank you anyway:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    newView = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (null == convertView) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selfie_list_view, null);
        holder.selfieView = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.selfie_bitmap);
        holder.selfieName = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.selfie_name);
        newView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();
    }

    SelfieRecord curr = list.get(position);
    String selfieName = curr.getBitmapName();
    final String selfiePath = curr.getBitmapPath();
    //Bitmap selfie = setPic(newView, selfiePath);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = holder.selfieView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            holder.selfieView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            int width = holder.selfieView.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = holder.selfieView.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.i(TAG, "view_width = " + width + " view_height =" + height);

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selfiePath, bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
            Log.i(TAG, "photo_width = " + photoW + " view_height =" + photoH);

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/width, photoH/height);

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selfiePath, bmOptions);

            holder.selfieView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return true;
        }
    });

    holder.selfieName.setText(selfieName);

    return newView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
int height;
int width;
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
        width = view.getLayoutParams().width;               
    }
});
```

Comment: these width and height might not be measured (in most cases they won't be), because they may be WRAP_CONTENT/FILL_PARENT/MATCH_PARENT

Comment: if `getWidth()` don't work for @Nick then he might get these values. in your cases they might be already measured (then `getWidth()` will also work for you)

Comment: yeah that's true, if my above written code doesn't works for me, i go for getWidth() afterwards(inside that view tree observer) :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. The reason is that targetW, and targetH, are accessed first while they are already zero, and onGlobalLayout() is called later. My problem is that I can not access variables inside the anonymous inner class.

Comment: i think declaring the variables as class fields will do